# Как отправить POST-запрос на некий Url  с помощью PHP?

Tags: rpc, php

Как отправить POST-запрос на некий Url  с помощью PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Самый мой полноценный ответ  - [CURL'om](http://ru.php.net/CURL)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='http://url' method='POST'>
  <input name='name'>
</form>
```